# webHttp Vs enableWebScript, which should be used for WCF REST POST request?

Tags: .net, wcf

What is the difference between webHttp and enableWebScript in WCF?  Which should I use for a WCF REST POST request?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To make your WCF service RESTful, you will have to use **WebHttp along with WebHttpBinding**

**To access your service from AJAX pages, you will have to use enableWebScript**.  This is similar to adding [ScriptService] attribute in asmx services.

So if the service has to be restful, but you donot want to access it from AJAX, you dont have to include enableWebScript.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924425.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675191.aspx

Comment: Hi Saranya, can you get me your email id? mine is sreekanth100k@gmail.com, I am newbie in .NET, I might need your help.

Comment: Why is this, though, @Saranya ?  I have web services that I call myself using AJAX, but their behavior is defined as webHttp. Just added a new "AJAX-enabled WCF endpoint" in VS, and I see it was automatically added by VS with enableWebScript behavior.  I've seen the two links you included in your answer, but I haven't found them helpful in explaining the differences.

Comment: but if I put enableWebScript, I can't access it from browser.. how can I do both?